# 2 Threads and 2 JTextArea

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

i need to wrote program that display time given by threads in 2 different JTextArea. Time is updated every randomly period of time. Also threads can be stop with button and resumed by clinking again. I have all GUI in other class.

My problem:
How to add reference to JTextArea in other class ?
How to stop Thread and resume with buttons ?

Here code from Thread Class:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    StopResume main = new StopResume();
    String name;
    Thread t;
    JTextArea a;

    String date;
    DateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 

    public MyThread(String threatName) {
        name = threatName;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //area1.append(date);
        //area2.append(date);
        //date = to.format(today);
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            t.sleep(1000);

            } 
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions and my attempts at answers:

> My problem: How to add reference to JTextArea in other class ?

I suggest that you don't as in general, one object should not directly manipulate another object's fields. Instead have your thread hold a reference to the GUI and have it call public methods of the GUI that accepts a String and in which the GUI will append to the JTextArea. Also, **be sure that this method is only called on the Swing event thread or EDT**. This can be done by queuing a Runnable onto the EDT by calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(yourRunnable)`. Or better -- use a SwingWorker. For more on this, please read [Concurrency in Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

> How to stop Thread and resume with buttons ?

Give the control class (the ActionListener class) a reference to the thread, and in the ActionListener, call public methods that stop or resume the thread's while loop (probably by changing a boolean variable).

---

Further notes:

- I see no randomness to your `Thread.sleep(...)` delay times. Do you need to give your MyThread class a Random object and use it to change the `Thread.sleep(...)` times?
- I see you're using a for loop rather than a while loop -- are you sure that you should be doing this?
- I don't see your threading class having any mechanism to pause its loop. Again a while loop whose boolean condition can be checked and changed might work better -- up to you.
- Your thread class creates its own copy of a StopResume object. If this is your main GUI, then you're setting yourself up for trouble. You should instead pass in a valid reference to the **displayed** GUI, probably through this thread class's constructor.

Comment: Ok. I add randomness and while lloop. So how can I change thread constructor to pass reference to GUI ?

Comment: @sokol: how do most constructors get references passed into them? I ask this question because this is a basic core Java concept you should and probably already know.